# Make refresh button rotate? WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

trying to get my button to rotate in my expander header when clicked, but I am getting an exception:

```
name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.'
```

Here is my XAML

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleRefreshExpanderButton" 
                 TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="RefreshExpanderButtonBorder"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <TextBlock Name="Sign" Text="&#x" FontFamily="{StaticResource Fonsda}" FontSize="{StaticResource LontSize}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SimpleRefreshExpanderButton"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                     To="180"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong :\

Comment: button name is `RefreshExpanderButtonBorder` - use it in Storyboard.TargetName. `SimpleRefreshExpanderButton` is resource name which is irrelevant

Comment: thanks, sadly the button is not turning 180 degrees :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the RenderTransform and the RotateTransform for your ToggleButton in order for this to work.  Without it, when your storyboard runs, it will not be able to find any "Angle" property to rotate.

Just add this to your ToggleButton:

```
        <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource SimpleRefreshExpanderButton}">
            <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform/>
            </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
        </ToggleButton>
```